# Meaning of "welcome distraction"

Tags: idioms

I want to know the meaning of *a welcome distraction*. It has no meaning when someone reads it first. I want to know the exact meaning. Is there a distraction that we can welcome?!

Comment: Imagine that you need to study for a test but 3 girls show up to your dorm room in bikinis...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A welcome distraction is a distraction that is good in some way. For example, you are studying very hard and need a break, and your mum brings in tea and cookies for you, and you pause and eat them. Your mum's act will then be a welcome distraction to you. Here, *[welcome](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/welcome_4)* is an adjective meaning you are pleased to have it.

Answer (score 3):

A welcome(d) distraction is one that occurs at an opportune time and allows the one being distracted to avoid an obligation, task, or other unpleasant circumstance.

It is welcome because at the time it occurs the person being distracted would prefer to not be concentrating on what would otherwise be commanding their attention.